# How to sort in a linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, io

So I am getting some files like this:

```
int pathLength = path.Length + 1;
var files = Directory.GetFiles ( path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories )
    .Where ( s => s.EndsWith ( ".bmp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ||
        s.EndsWith ( ".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
        .Select ( s => s.Substring ( pathLength, s.Length - pathLength ) )

    .ToList ( );
```

and was before sorting like this:

```
FileComparer fileComparer = new FileComparer ( );
files.Sort ( fileComparer );
```

But for Sort I need to use ToList. I am wondering if I can just add the Sort to the Linq the same way and get rid of ToList?

Comment: You're also looking for the `Path.GetExtension` method. Plus, you don't need the second paramter to `Substring`.  See my answer.

Comment: Sorry just saw it. FileComparer implements IComparer<string> where if a path has \\ it comes first (because it's a directory), otherwise it's a filename, comes after. Else just a normal string comparison.

Comment: Ok, then you will need a ThenBy clause after your OrderBy clause as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`OrderBy` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534863.aspx):

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { ".bmp", ".jpg" };
int pathLength = path.Length + 1;
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)))
    .Select(s => s.Substring(pathLength))
    .OrderBy(s => s, new FileComparer());
```

You can replace your `FileComparer` class with

```
.OrderBy(s => !s.Contains('\\')).ThenBy(s => s)
```

Since `false < true`, this will sort strings that start with `\\` before other ones.

Comment: Thanks, this seem to be the best answer. I had to change your last OrderBy edit to s.Contains because \\ could be anywhere. Sorry didn't mention that. It's working great. I tested the speed is about the same. Does using FileComparer puts more overhead than using your last edit?

Comment: @Joan: You're welcome.  I would guess that your `FileComparer` (assuming it's well-written) would be a tiny bit faster.  However, LINQ calls are shorter.

Comment: Thanks, yeah my FileComparer is as simple it can be but the speed was the same and even if it was 10ms longer, your code is more elegant :O

Answer (score 2):

Use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method.

Your code will change from -

```
files.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.fileName, y.fileName));
```

to -

```
files.OrderBy(x => x.fileName);
```

**Update**

```
files.OrderBy(x => x.fileName.Contains(@"\\")).ThenBy(x => x.fileName);
```

Comment: No, it won't.  He's not using that overload.

Comment: He could get rid of the comparer and express the comparison directly in the OrderBy clause.

Comment: Looking at his comment, he certainly can't.

Answer (score 1):

```
.OrderBy(f => f, new FileComparer())
```

(this assumes FileComparer implements `IComparer<string>`)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can do to improve your code :

- like said previously, use **OrderBy** for sort
- write your request as a **LINQ expression** rather than successive method calls :

  ```
  var files = (from file in Directory.GetFiles ( path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories )
              where file.EndsWith ( ".bmp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ||
               file.EndsWith ( ".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
               orderby new FileComparer()
               select file);
  ```

  The code above does the same than yours but is more elegant.
- To get path, extension, file name... I strongly recommend you to use **System.IO.Path** helpers methods rather than perform string operations like substring or contains !!
- Rather than use Directory.GetFiles you could instantiate a **DirectoryInfo** and call the GetFiles method : this one has the advantage to return an array of FileInfo, which exposes directly properties like extension, file name...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, would there be a speed difference between the query syntax vs the dot notation?

Comment: No, it is simply syntax-sugar. The compiler takes the LINQ request to translate it to method calls using lambdas, then finally to delegates : finally, IMHO the resulting MSIL should be the same.